# Python script executing by PHP

Tags: php, python

I've got a question. I'm gonna make few charts on my website, but I would like to have all the time fresh data.

I've got a TXT file: `temperature.txt`
It's getting information every 1 minute about temperature. Now, I would like to make a chart for example "Temperature in last hour". I would like to make HTML/PHP page to show me a chart.

**What's my problem?**
I would like to use python script to:
Get last 60 lines from `temperature.txt` and save them as `Temperature1Hour.txt` in my `/htdocs/` folder.

And I don't know how to write PHP script to execute my Python script. It's server-based only, client will click a button on site and everything will execute on server.

Is it possible? If yes, How? Is there any php function to start python script?

Comment: This really seems more like the kind of task suited for a database so you wouldn't need to periodically extract from the text file. It could just efficiently give you all the data from the last hour with the appropriate query. Ignoring that fact, the extract task is something you want to do periodically. You want a scheduled job, not something called on the fly from PHP. That would be a cron job if you're running Linux, but that has the issue of not being able to read from PHP while you're writing in Python.

Comment: Why do you need to execute a python script for this? PHP can easily get the last 60 lines from a file and save them to another file. But if you really want to execute a python script from PHP, use the `exec()` function.

Comment: I really need to keep my trap shut and read the problem more. If it's a manual kick off, then I'm wrong about a scheduled job being appropriate. I still think a database is better suited, though; they're designed for efficient data retrieval like that. File contention is still issue; what if two users click the button at the same time? @Barmar His temperature file is getting a line every minute. After a year, it will be over 500,000 lines long. If user wait time is a concern, will PHP be able to do that efficiently enough? Not that I have any idea if Łukasz is doing this asynchronously.

Comment: @jpmc26 Why would Python be significantly faster at reading the file than PHP is? The bottleneck is usually the disk, not the application software.

Comment: @Barmar Hence my comment about doing it asynchronously. If the Python call is to kick off the executable and then not wait or give the user some kind of AJAX waiting page, then it's different. It's also possible Python has some kind of optimization that would do it faster; that's a total unknown. I was just asking how efficient PHP is at it; I thought maybe I would be surprised. My recommendation is still a database.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't use PHP or Python, I'd just use the shell command `tail -60 temperature.txt > Temporature1Hour.txt`.

Comment: But I need to do it everytime I click button "Show temperature in last hour", than any script (python is easier than PHP) can sort 60 lines for me and put into new txt file, which is used to make a chart.

Comment: If you use a database, you don't have to do it at all. You can just do a `SELECT` that gives you the 60 most recent rows. If you really want to stick with Python, then `exec` will work as Barmar stated. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php. Or you can use `exec` to make the shell call Barmar suggested.